# Block Go routine in a shared library

Tags: multithreading, go, block, condition-variable

I have shared library which provides a function that will go to waiting state during processing.  The waiting is achieved by the condition variable provided by c++. Any one knows how to call this function correctly from Go?

C++ functions:

I have a queue to store all the tasks to be processed.

```
queue<Task> tasks;
Mutex mutex;
condition_variable cv;

void process(string img_path) {
    std::unique_lock<Mutex> lock(mutex);
    Task task(img_path);
    tasks.push_back(task);
    cv.wait(); //wait the task to be processed, because i have to process the tasks in a batch way using GPU
}
```

The above code is just used to illustrate the key component which is the blocking wait function of condition variable.  It will be compiled into a dynamic library.   If called from Python, I found a solution illustrated in [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock). Any one knows how to call from Golang?

Comment: Can you share some code so we have a better idea of what you intend to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem boils down to [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) and the condition variable is just obscuring things. As a tiny demonstration of what you can do, consider a go program and a library built from a C++ file.

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: func.so
// void someFunc();
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Before C stuff.\n")

    t0 := time.Now()
    C.someFunc()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", time.Now().Sub(t0))
}
```

And now the C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

extern "C" {
    void someFunc();
}    
void someFunc() {
    sleep(10);
    std::cout << "And print something\n";
}
```

Build it and run it like this:

```
% g++ -Wall -Wextra -o func.o -c func.cc -fPIC
% gcc -Wall -Wextra -o func.so -shared func.o
% go build
% LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./cgofun
Before C stuff.                                  
And print something
10.000273351s
```

Using the same technique you should be able to call a function that blocks on a condition variable. The go runtime won't care and will keep the calling goroutine blocked for as long as necessary.